# Application icon disappears from Taskbar & Startmenu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, start-menu

I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 Ultimate and the first thing I load is always Firefox. This time, however, it appears that Windows cannot locate the program icons for the links in the Start Menu or Taskbar.

[image]

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling Firefox, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [rebuilding the icon cache db](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t71.html). Open a command prompt session and type in the following:

1. Type `cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local`
2. Click OK
3. Type `attrib –h IconCache.db`
4. Click OK
5. Type `del IconCache.db`
6. Click OK
7. Type `start explorer`
8. Click OK.

Comment: Don't forget to kill the `explorer` process before deleting the IconCache.db

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this one
http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/05/story-of-windows-7-and-empty-all.html